# I was suffered an error when I learn useing tensorflow to build a fully connected neutral network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to build a fully connected neutral network by tensorflow,I use the code like this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

import load

def get_chunk(samples, labels, chunkSize):
    if len(samples) != len(labels):
        raise Exception('dataset is wrong!!!!!')

    print(np.shape(labels))
    stepStart = 0
    i = 0
    while stepStart < len(samples):
        stepEnd = stepStart + chunkSize
        if stepEnd < len(samples):
            print('==================this is the shape of placeholder======================')
            print(np.shape(labels[stepStart: stepEnd]))
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            yield i, samples[stepStart:stepEnd], labels[stepStart: stepStart]
            print('========================================================================')
            i += 1
        stepStart = stepEnd

class Network():
    def __init__(self, num_hidden, batch_size):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.test_batch_size = 500
        self.num_hidden = num_hidden

        self.image_size = load.image_size
        self.num_channels = 1

        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.tf_train_samples = None
        self.tf_train_labels = None
        self.tf_test_samples = None
        self.tf_test_labels = None

    def define_graph(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            self.tf_train_samples = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, shape=(self.batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels)  )
            #self.tf_train_samples = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, shape=(self.batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels) )
            self.tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, shape=(self.batch_size, num_labels)  )
            self.tf_test_samples = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, shape=(self.test_batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels)  )

            fc1_weights = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([image_size*image_size, self.num_hidden], stddev=0.1)  )
            fc1_biases = tf.Variable( tf.constant(0.1, shape=[self.num_hidden])  )

            fc2_weights = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([self.num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1)  )
            fc2_biases = tf.Variable( tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_labels])  )

            def model(data):
                shape = data.get_shape().as_list()
                print('this is model() ============================================')
                print(data.get_shape(), shape)
                reshape = tf.reshape(data, [shape[0], shape[1]*shape[2]*shape[3]])
                print(reshape.get_shape(), fc1_weights.get_shape(), fc1_biases.get_shape())
                print('model ended ================================================')
                hidden = tf.nn.relu( tf.matmul(reshape, fc1_weights) + fc1_biases  )

                return tf.matmul(hidden, fc2_weights) + fc2_biases

            logits = model(self.tf_train_samples)
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=self.tf_train_labels) )
            self.optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(self.loss)

            self.train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
            self.test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax( model(self.tf_test_samples)  )

    def run(self):
        self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
        with self.session as session:
            tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
            #tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

            print('start Training')
            for i, samples, labels in get_chunk( train_samples, train_labels, chunkSize=self.batch_size  ):
                print('this is the start of get placeholder')
                _, l, predictions = session.run(
                        [self.optimizer, self.loss, self.train_prediction],
                        feed_dict={ self.tf_train_samples:samples, self.tf_train_labels:labels}    
                )
                accuracy, _ = self.accuracy(predictions, labels)
                if i % 50 == 0:
                    print('accuracy:'+str(accuracy))

    def accuracy(self, predictions, labels, need_confusion_matrix = False):
        #pass
        _predictions = np.argmax(predictions, 1)
        _labels = np.argmax(labels, 1)
        cm = confusion_matrix(_labels, _predictions) if need_confusion_matrix else None

        accuracy = (100.0*np.sum(_predictions == labels) / print.shape[0])
        return accuracy, cm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_samples, train_labels = load._train_samples, load._train_labels
    test_samples, test_labels = load._test_samples, load._test_labels

    print('Training set', train_samples.shape, train_labels.shape)
    print('    Test set', test_samples.shape, test_labels.shape)

    image_size = load.image_size
    num_labels = load.num_labels
    num_channels = 1#load.channels
    net = Network(num_hidden=128, batch_size=100)
    net.define_graph()
    net.run()
```

and when I run the code , it give errors like this:

```
panda@dyy:~/code/number_test$ python bp.py 
Training set (73257, 32, 32, 1) (73257, 10)
    Test set (26032, 32, 32, 1) (26032, 10)
this is model() ============================================
(100, 32, 32, 1) [100, 32, 32, 1]
(100, 1024) (1024, 128) (128,)
model ended ================================================
this is model() ============================================
(500, 32, 32, 1) [500, 32, 32, 1]
(500, 1024) (1024, 128) (128,)
model ended ================================================
2017-05-27 13:48:07.343556: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-27 13:48:07.343640: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-27 13:48:07.343653: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-27 13:48:07.343661: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

2017-05-27 13:48:07.343668: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
WARNING:tensorflow:From bp.py:75: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
start Training
(73257, 10)
==================this is the shape of placeholder======================
(100, 10)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is the start of get placeholder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bp.py", line 110, in <module>
    net.run()
  File "bp.py", line 83, in run
    feed_dict={ self.tf_train_samples:samples, self.tf_train_labels:labels}    
  File "/home/panda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/panda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 961, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(100, 10)'
panda@dyy:~/code/number_test$
```

Iguess it mean I use the placeholder wrong, I learn the program from this github
[enter link description here](https://github.com/CreatCodeBuild/TensorFlow-and-DeepLearning-Tutorial/blob/master/Season1/7-9/dp.py)  ,i copyed some code here, It is not the problem of enviroment because i run it correct, but I can not find the different about where I was wrong, So, If someone can give me some help.

Comment: My guess is your loader didn't load samples correctly. You should print out the samples shape and have a look.

Comment: no this code info :Training set (73257, 32, 32, 1) (73257, 10)
    Test set (26032, 32, 32, 1) (26032, 10) was the data loaded from the load ,and due to I learn this code from github so I can run the right code, so I promise the load mudel is correct, the problem was in the code I give in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the reason by print my code and the demo from the github. It is because the function get_chunk,Ireturn the List labels[stepStart: stepStart].
def get_chunk(samples, labels, chunkSize):
    if len(samples) != len(labels):
        raise Exception('dataset is wrong!!!!!')

```
print(np.shape(labels))
stepStart = 0
i = 0
while stepStart < len(samples):
    stepEnd = stepStart + chunkSize
    if stepEnd < len(samples):
        print('==================this is the shape of placeholder======================')
        print(np.shape(labels[stepStart: stepEnd]))
        print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        yield i, samples[stepStart:stepEnd], labels[stepStart: stepStart]
        print('========================================================================')
        i += 1
    stepStart = stepEnd
```

here is the picture I printed:

[the wrong code of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEsbG.jpg)

[the right code from demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W0Wd.jpg)

Thanks Jason for answear my question.